# How to inherit from another Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a test application structured like so:

- Application.cfc
- ApplicationProxy.cfc
- index.cfm
- sub_app/

  - Application.cfc
  - index.cfm

and I want my sub app to inherit all variables and events from the top level Application.cfc.

I have read and implemented [Sean Corfield's ApplicationProxy method](http://corfield.org/entry/Extending_Your_Root_Applicationcfc) for extending an Application component but I can't get it to work as when I visit sub_app/index.cfm I get this error:

```
Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface ApplicationProxy.
```

From the error I can only guess that the application is looking in the wrong place, how do I correct this?

Application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent name="Application" output="true">

<cfset THIS.name = "testAppA">
<cfset THIS.sessionManagement="Yes">
<cfset THIS.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,0,10,0)>
<cfset THIS.sessionTimeout = createtimespan(0,0,10,0)>
<cfset THIS.clientManagement = true>
<cfset THIS.clientStorage = "cookie">
<cfset THIS.loginStorage = "cookie">
<cfset THIS.setDomainCookies = false>
<cfset THIS.setClientCookies = true>
<cfset THIS.scriptProtect = true>
<cfset THIS.secureJSON = true> 

<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returntype="void">

    <cfset APPLICATION.name = "testAppA">
    <cfset APPLICATION.test = "test var">

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onSessionStart" returntype="void">

    <cfset SESSION.loggedIn = 1>

</cffunction>    

</cfcomponent>
```

ApplicationProxy:

```
<cfcomponent name="ApplicationProxy" extends="Application">
</cfcomponent>
```

index.cfm:

```
<a href="sub_app/index.cfm">Sub app</a>
```

sub_app/Application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent extends="ApplicationProxy" output="true">

    <!---

            Uses parent Application settings

    --->

</cfcomponent>
```

sub_app/index.cfm:

```
<a href="../index.cfm">Parent app</a>

<cfdump var="#Application#">
```

Comment: Perhaps this other answer will help explain it: [Extending application.cfc in a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307423/extending-application-cfc-in-a-subdirectory/307441#307441)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do is create ApplicationProxy.cfc file with all function you need to inherit and then  extends in Application.cfc wherever needed. I am using this method since long time and no issue face with this approach.