# How to have one component extend another component?

Tags: coldfusion, components, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to extend a component in my application located on a local server (the url to access to my application is defined like that: http://my.new.application/)

Here is the structure of my application on the server (I cannot change the name of the main folder) is:

- folder my.new.application

  - application.cfc
  - index.cfm
  - Folder

    - application.cfc
    - page.cfm

The folder `folder` has it's own Application.cfc file extending the master
one and overloading the `onRequestStart` function with an empty one.

But when I try to implement that:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Application" extends="my.new.application/Application">

 <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
    <!--- override the parent implementation to remove authentication for this
          part of the application --->
 </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

I get the following error:

> Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface my.new.application/Application.

On the production server the main folder is named `myApplication`. If I do the same:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Application" extends="myApplication/Application">
```

It works perfectly.

Could you please help me in order to solve the problem for the local server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend a CFC using a relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287187/extend-a-cfc-using-a-relative-path)

Comment: I have tried these solutions, but it's not working.

Comment: Can't have slashes in the component path in `extends=`, only dots.

Comment: Is the folder actually named `something.something.something` (with the periods)? That may be the issue as periods in this context normally map to folders themselves; `something\something\something`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending application.cfc in a subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307423/extending-application-cfc-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: If I recall, Application.cfc is a special beast, and you can't simply extend it like you would other components.

Comment: @coeurdange57 I guess this question had already been asked and answered in few other posts.. Check out them

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. But if I put extends="my.new.application/Application" or extends="my.new.application.Application" I obtain the same error "Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface test.budgetting.eurostat.cec/Application. " I don't know how to solve that because the name of my main folder on my server is "my.new.application". I read the various topics but I don't find a solution. I try that <cfcomponent displayname="Application" extends="../Application"> and I obtain the error "  The ../Application component or interface cannot extend itself."

Comment: I suggest using dots in your folder names is a bad idea. Keep it to letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores.

Comment: Read the link in "Extending Application.cfc in a subdirectory" that @AlE.posted. Your solution is in using an `ApplicationProxy.cfc` as described there.

Comment: Might you have to add a mapping?

Comment: @coeurdange57 Why you shouldn't use the same application name like as in production server??